# Sort list by given order of indices

Tags: python, sorting, list

I have a list of lines read from a file. I need to sort the list by time stamp. I have parsed out the time stamp using regular expressions and place them into a separate list. The indices of the two lists will match. Once I sort the list of time stamps, I can get the order of indices.

Is there a way to apply the same order of indices to the original list of lines? The result should be the sorted list of original lines.

Example:

```
listofLines =  ['log opened 16-Feb-2010 06:37:56 UTC', 
                '06:37:58 Custom parameters are in use',
                'log closed 16-Feb-2010 05:26:47 UTC']
listofTimes = ['06:37:56', '06:37:58', '05:26:47']
sortedIndex = [2,0,1]
```

Comment: Rather than do extra work to figure out the indices and then apply them back to the other list, why not pair the values up before sorting (for example, using `zip`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you could do

```
[line for (time,line) in sorted(zip(listofTimes, listofLines))]
```

But if you have (or could write) a function to automatically extract the time from the line,

```
def extract_time(line):
    ...
    return time
```

you could also do

```
listofLines.sort(key=extract_time)
```

or if you want to keep the original list intact,

```
sorted(listofLines, key=extract_time)
```

Answer (score 51):

```
[listofLines[i] for i in sortedIndex]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(zip(listofTimes, listofLines))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the original list because you, say, hold references to it elsewhere, you can assign to it the sorted list:

```
my_list[:] = [my_list[i] for i in sorted_indexes]  # [:] is key!
```