# How can i get a permutation given indexes?

Tags: python, arrays, permutation

I've got a list of objects:

```
array = [object0,object1,object2,object3,object4]
```

and i want to change the order of the items given a permutation:

```
permutation = [ 2 , 4 , 0 , 1 , 3 ]
```

Is there a command in python that will do something like:

```
result = Permute(array,permutation)

result = [object2,object4,object0,object1,object3]
```

I know i can do it with a simple `for` loop....

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098250/in-place-way-to-apply-a-permutation-to-a-list-inverse-of-sorting-by-key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort list by given order of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260427/sort-list-by-given-order-of-indices)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we are assuming that `permutation` is a proper permutation of `0-n` (each appears exactly once), then the following code should work:

```
result=[array[i] for i in permutation]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Python, this is easy to do with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
result = [array[i] for i in permutation]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness a version with no *for* at all:

```
seed = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
permutation = [1, 2, 0]
result = map(lambda i: seed[i], permutation)
print result # --> ['bar', 'baz', 'foo']
```

I'd rather stick with the list comprehension guys, though. ;)

Comment: For even more completeness, you don't need the lambda, you could use the (even more ugly): `map(seed.__getitem__, permutation)`

Answer (score 0):

Use shuffle method from numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
print(arr)
```

[1 7 5 2 9 4 3 6 0 8]

Reference:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html

Comment: Hi! This doesn't appear to answer the question at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can use index swapping.
You a have two array a and b

```
def swap_random(a, b):
"""Randomly swap entries in two arrays."""
# Indices to swap
    swap_inds = np.random.random(size=len(a)) < 0.5 # your threshold 

# Make copies of arrays a and b for output
    a_out = np.copy(a)
    b_out = np.copy(b)

# Swap values
   a_out[swap_inds] = b[swap_inds]
   b_out[swap_inds] = a[swap_inds]

   return a_out, b_out
```

So, do the test

```
d = np.array(range(0,15))
r = np.array(range(16,31))

display(d,r)

>>> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
>>> array([16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30])


display(swap_random(d, r))
>>> (array([ 0, 17,  2,  3, 20, 21, 22,  7, 24, 25, 10, 11, 28, 13, 14]),
>>> array([16,  1, 18, 19,  4,  5,  6, 23,  8,  9, 26, 27, 12, 29, 30]))
```

Comment: Hi! While numpy is often a good solution for anything related to big arrays of numbers, I think this answer would be more helpful if the first sentence was something along the lines of "Consider using numpy for this", and then you code began with `import numpy as np`. Otherwise, your answer only makes sense for those who are already familiar enough with numpy.

Comment: Also, on closer look, it's not obvious what's the relation between the function `swap_random` you propose and the OP's question about applying a permutation. In fact, applying a permutation is extremely easy in numpy, using the permutation as the index for the other array: `def apply_permutation(perm, arr): return np.array(arr)[perm]`